# Facebook Authentication Page Scroll Issue?

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface

I am using facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1. There is an bug regarding scroll on authentication confirmation page.

Steps to get issue:

- After authenticate user it show confirmation dialog with text **"You are already authorize"** and two button **OK/CANCEL**.
- In small screen it doesn't show these two button, it just display n went..at bottom(not visible) somewhere of layout, and since **layout not scroll-able** so u can't scroll it.
- I tested same on emulator, if I press Tab then focus control shift to these button still page is not scrollable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: Issue is fixed in new [release build](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/detail?name=socialauth-android-sdk-2.5.zip&can=2&q=).

Scrolling issue got solved, but with authentication done it show "You are already authorize XXX".